# Synthesizing CGFloat property in iOS

Tags: ios, properties

I declared a property as below. From my readings on the web, it is not clear if I should also synthesize as below. I have seen supporting blog posts for two different approaches.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat someFloat;
```

Then in the implementation:

```
@synthesize someFloat = _someFloat;
```

I have also seen in some cases:

```
@synthesize someFloat;
```

From readings, I understand that "someFloat" is a property name, and "_someFloat" is created through the synthesis. So I am under the impression that the first way is correct. However, I have used the second approach without problems. And I have seen the second approach in other code and blogs.

**Can someone tell me what is the correct way and why?**

Comment: You can probably get 5 different "correct" answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you no longer need to manually write `@synthesize` anymore. In your example, if you write

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat someFloat;
```

The compiler will automatically synthesize it for you, which would be equivalent to you writing

```
@synthesize someFloat = _someFloat;
```

Hence, you would be able to access the property through `self.someFloat` or access the ivar within the implementation file by using `_someFloat`.

If, however, you manually synthesize it like

```
@synthesize someFloat;
```

The compiler automatically creates a backing ivar titled `someFloat`... thereby, you would still be able to access the variable through the getter `self.someFloat` (that is, equivalent to `[self someFloat]` call).

Or, you could access the ivar by simply using `someFloat` somewhere within the implementation...

In general, it's not recommended to synthesize like this because it's quite easy to accidentally use the ivar when you meant to access the variable using the getter.

**EXCEPTION TO THE RULE**

The compiler still gets confused with synthesizing variables sometimes, however, in certain instances. For example, if you have a class that is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, then you still *need to write* the `@synthesize` manually (assuming, of course, you actually want to synthesize the property... you likely don't though...).

The reason for this is two-fold: (1) the compiler doesn't seem to understand these properties very well yet (or at least it doesn't in the cases I've worked with), and (2) many times, you actually **DON'T** want to `@synthesize` properties on an `NSManagedObject` subclass... rather, you want them to be `@dynamic` instead (so the getter/setter will be generated at runtime, per requirements of `NSManagedObject` subclass magic).

Comment: omg... all those old blog posts about synthesizing should be taken down. This answer should be the only thing so that people don't get confused. thanks a million.

Comment: JRG - do you know if you **actually need** the assign these days (2015), with something that is not an object, such as a CGFloat?  Thanks!

Comment: @JoeBlow, I *would* write the `assign` specified, just to be 100% clear to any readers. However, it should be fine (AFAIK) without it (compiler will default to `assign` for primitives).

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the `@synthesize` statement, the compiler will generate the same thing as if you had:

```
@synthesize someFloat = _someFloat;
```